# Why is the text element not being changed when I try with a function

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>functionTesting</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id = "test" >test</p>
        <script type = "text/javascript" >
        function change(string){
            //return string + ": Modified"
            document:getElementById("test").innerHTML = string + ": Modified"
        }
        change("1234")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the test is never changed to "1234: Modified. It seems to stay as "test" unless I get the element outside the function then change it.

Comment: You have a typo `document:getElementById("test")` should be `document.getElementById("test")`

Comment: It's `document.getElementById`, NOT `document:getElementById`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have a syntax error. Change:

```
document:getElementById
```

To:

```
document.getElementById
```

(colon to a period)

Answer (score -1):

This line:

```
document:getElementById("test").innerHTML = string + ": Modified";
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = string + ": Modified";
```